# coding automatic weights in Scripting

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, armature, bones

How Can I make "with automatic weights" by Scripting?

Like the Image But by Python

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have selected the mesh and the armature:

```
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='ARMATURE_AUTO')
```

Here's how to find this out:

If you enable Python tooltips in your preferences and hover over 'With Automatic Weights', it will show you:

[image]

If you type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>C</kbd> it will copy that string to clipboard.  You can then go to the Python console ad type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>V</kbd> to past it at the prompt:

[image: pasting the clipboard to the prompt.]

Putting this all together in pseudocode

```
myObject = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']  # Replace with statement to select object
myArmature =  bpy.context.scene.objects['Armature'] # Replace with statement to select the correct armature

# Assumes that nothing else is selected at the moment
myObject.select_set(True)  # Must select the object first
myArmature.select_set(True) # Then select the armature
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='ARMATURE_AUTO') # then parent
```